# Fazer com que rota POST HTTP atenda somente 1 (uma) requisição por vez (Web Api c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-web-api, fila

Eu estou tentando criar uma POC para aprender criar uma rota que execute uma espécie de fila para as requisições.

Criei a seguinte Controller:

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
private static int _queuePosition = 0;
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);


public async void Post()
{
  var sendDate = DateTime.Now;
  _queuePosition++;
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    //Inicio processo
    var InicioProcesso = DateTime.Now;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //10 seg
    Email.SendMail($"Data de entrada na Fila: {sendDate} | Data Inicio Processo: {InicioProcesso} | Data de envio: {DateTime.Now} | Requisições na fila: {_queuePosition}");
    semaphore.Release();
  }
  finally
  {
    _queuePosition--;
  }
}
```

Quando envio duas requisições com uma diferença de 2 seg recebo os seguintes e-mails de Log:

- Data de entrada na Fila: 01/02/2023 16:19:55 | Data Inicio Processo:
  01/02/2023 16:19:55 | Data de envio: 01/02/2023 16:20:05 |
  Requisições na fila: 2
- Data de entrada na Fila: 01/02/2023 16:19:57 | Data Inicio Processo:
  01/02/2023 16:19:57 | Data de envio: 01/02/2023 16:20:07 |
  Requisições na fila: 2

O certo não era o Inicio do Processo da 2 requisição iniciar somente depois que a 1 requisição finalizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque *controllers* são construídos **a cada requisição**. Como o semáforo está sendo inicializado na construção do *controller* cada requisição usa um semáforo diferente.

Você precisa fazer com que a instância do semáforo seja a mesma entre diferentes requisições.

Abaixo um código completo e funcional em ASP.NET Core com o comportamento desejado. Note que mesmo que esteja usando .NET Framework a ideia continua sendo a mesma.

**Program.cs**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<SemaphoreSlim>(new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
// ^ Isso faz a injeção dessa instância de SemaphoreSlim como singleton 
// uma instância para toda a aplicação

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**ValuesController.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Projeto.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public ValuesController(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)     
        => _semaphore = semaphore;

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post()
    {
        var sendDate = DateTime.Now;
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
                
        var inicioProcesso = DateTime.Now;
        Thread.Sleep(15000); 
        
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Data de entrada na Fila: {sendDate} " + 
            "| Data Inicio Processo: {inicioProcesso} " + 
            "| Data de envio: {DateTime.Now} " + 
            "| Requisições na fila: {_queuePosition}"
        );
            
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso aparentemente resolveu o meu problema, obrigado.